# ¿Cómo hacer una consulta con IF en php?

Tags: php, html, phpmyadmin, condiciones, modal

Estoy haciendo una página web para consultar el estado de la reparación de equipos de cómputo, tengo problemas al realizar la condicional con IF en php. [Esta es la base de datos a la que me estoy conectando para realizar la búsqueda de datos en la consulta](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lJfC4.png). En la base de datos, la columna de "ReparacionesCodigo" almacena las órdenes de reparación, y la columna de "ReparacionesTerminada" indica el estado de las reparaciones: 0 es para no terminada, 1 es para terminada.

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['enviar'])) {
    $busqueda = $_POST['busqueda'];
    $consultar = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Consulta WHERE ReparacionesCodigo LIKE '$busqueda'");
    $result = mysql_fetch_row($consultar);
} ?>
```

Ese es el código en php que estoy utilizando para realizar la consulta, en donde 'busqueda' es el nombre del input en donde se escribe el código de reparación y 'enviar' es el nombre del botón que al presionar busca el registro en la base de datos. Lo que quiero lograr hacer es mostrar unas ventanas emergentes con un mensaje diferente dependiendo del estado de reparación. Si tiene un 1, mostrar un mensaje avisando que está terminada esa orden de reparación, si hay un 0 mostrar un mensaje que aún está en taller de reparaciones. Solo sé como hacer la consulta para buscar por código de reparación en la columna de "ReparacionesCodigo", pero no sé como condicionar esas ventanas emergentes dependiendo de el valor en los registros de la columna "ReparacionesTerminada".

Intenté realizar la condicional en IF de esta manera, pero no realiza nada, solo recarga la página. El else de al final muestra otra ventana emergente que avisa al usuario que no se encuentra la orden, cuando haya un error de entrada por parte de los usuarios.

```
<?php if($result["ReparacionesTerminada"]=="0"){ ?>
    (Código de ventana emergente)           
}

<?php if($result["ReparacionesTerminada"]=="1"){ ?>
    (Código de ventana emergente)                
}

<?php else { ?>
    (Código de ventana emergente)  
}
```

Código completo:

```
<?php
include 'ejecutar.php';
?>

<!-- Modal -->
                  <div class="modal fade " id="demoModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="demoModal" aria-hidden="true">
                    <div class="modal-dialog  modal-dialog-centered  " role="document">
                      <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-body py-sm-4 px-sm-5">
                          <button type="button" class="close " data-dismiss="modal"
                           aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                          </button>
                          <div class="text-center pt-5">
                            <img src="https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/128/3067/3067416.png">
                              <h3>Consulta de orden</h3>
                                <p class="text-muted">
                                  Consulta el estado del servicio que has solicitado ingresando tu número de orden asignado.
                                </p>
                          </div>
                          <form name="consulta" action="" method="get">
                            <div class="form-group">
                              <label>Número de orden</label>
                              <input type="number" name="busqueda" class="form-control" min="0" placeholder="Ingresa tu número de orden (4 cifras)">
                            </div>
                            <button type="submit" name="enviar" class="btn btn-cstm-dark btn-cta" style="display:block; margin: 0 auto;">Enviar</button>

                    <?php 
                    if(isset($_POST['enviar'])) {
                        $busqueda = $_POST['busqueda'];
                        $consultar = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Consulta WHERE ReparacionesCodigo LIKE '$busqueda'");
                        $result = mysql_fetch_row($consultar);
                    } ?>

                    <?php if($result["ReparacionesTerminada"]=="0"){ ?>
                        <div class="modal fade "   id="demoModal"  tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="demoModal" aria-hidden="true">
                            <div class="modal-dialog  modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
                                <div class="modal-content">
                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                    </button>
                                    <div class="modal-body">
                                        <div class="px-3 pt-3 text-center">
                                            <div class="event-type error">
                                                <div class="event-indicator ">
                                                    <svg style="width:60px;height:60px" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                                                        <path fill="#fff" d="M19,6.41L17.59,5L12,10.59L6.41,5L5,6.41L10.59,12L5,17.59L6.41,19L12,13.41L17.59,19L19,17.59L13.41,12L19,6.41Z" />
                                                    </svg>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <h3 class="pt-3">Su equipo aún no está listo</h3>
                                            <p class="text-muted">
                                                Seguimos trabajando en él en nuestro taller de reparaciones.
                                            </p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modal-footer text-md-right">
                                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-cstm-secondary" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" >Aceptar</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>                  
                    }

                    <?php if($result["ReparacionesTerminada"]=="1"){ ?>
                        <div class="modal fade "   id="demoModal"  tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="demoModal" aria-hidden="true">
                            <div class="modal-dialog  modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
                                <div class="modal-content">
                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                    </button>
                                    <div class="modal-body">
                                        <div class="px-3 pt-3 text-center">
                                            <div class="event-type error">
                                                <div class="event-indicator ">
                                                    <svg style="width:60px;height:60px" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                                                        <path fill="#fff" d="M19,6.41L17.59,5L12,10.59L6.41,5L5,6.41L10.59,12L5,17.59L6.41,19L12,13.41L17.59,19L19,17.59L13.41,12L19,6.41Z" />
                                                    </svg>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <h3 class="pt-3">¡Su equipo ya está listo!</h3>
                                            <p class="text-muted">
                                                Está listo para su entrega al dueño.
                                            </p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modal-footer text-md-right">
                                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-cstm-secondary" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" >Aceptar</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>                  
                    }

                    <?php else { ?>
                        <div class="modal fade "   id="demoModal"  tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="demoModal" aria-hidden="true">
                            <div class="modal-dialog  modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
                                <div class="modal-content">
                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                    </button>
                                    <div class="modal-body">
                                        <div class="px-3 pt-3 text-center">
                                            <div class="event-type error">
                                                <div class="event-indicator ">
                                                    <svg style="width:60px;height:60px" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                                                        <path fill="#fff" d="M19,6.41L17.59,5L12,10.59L6.41,5L5,6.41L10.59,12L5,17.59L6.41,19L12,13.41L17.59,19L19,17.59L13.41,12L19,6.41Z" />
                                                    </svg>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <h3 class="pt-3">Error en orden</h3>
                                            <p class="text-muted">
                                                No se encontró la orden ingresada. Por favor, verifique su número de orden y vuelva a intentar.
                                            </p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modal-footer text-md-right">
                                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-cstm-secondary" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" >Aceptar</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>                  
                    }
                          </form>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
 <!-- Modal Ends -->
```

Comment: Los corchetes de cierre van dentro del bloque `<?php`.

Comment: Por nada del mundo deberias estar usuando la libreria mysql_query a no ser que desees tener un boquete de seguridad nefasto.

Comment: Usa una SweetAlert basica para tal propósito, pero pon todo el código para ayudarte mejor.

Comment: @OCHOA Ya lo actualicé con código completo

Answer (score 0):

Como sabrás no puedo replicar tu ejemplo porque no tengo todo.

Te dejo un ejemplo de como lo puedes implementar, obviamente las variables **$result** y **$busqueda** son tus variables.

Copia el siguiente código y ejecútalo en un archivo PHP aparte y mira como puedes adaptarlo a tu sistema.

```
<!Doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/limonte-sweetalert2/11.4.24/sweetalert2.all.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php
        $busqueda = 35483; // Cambiar a 0 para probar
        $result = 1; // Cambiar entre 0 y 1 para probar

        if ($busqueda != 0) {
            if ($result == 0) {
            ?>
                <script>
                    Swal.fire({
                        icon: 'error',
                        title: 'Sorry',
                        text: 'La Reparación <?php echo $busqueda ?> no está Terminada'
                    })
                </script>
            <?php
            }
            elseif ($result == 1) {
            ?>
                <script>
                    Swal.fire({
                        icon: 'success',
                        title: 'Listo !!!',
                        text: 'La Reparación <?php echo $busqueda ?> está Terminada'
                    })
                </script>
            <?php
            }
        }
        else{
        ?>
            <script>
                Swal.fire({
                    icon: 'warning',
                    title: 'Ups !!!',
                    text: 'La Reparación <?php echo $busqueda ?> No Existe !!!'
                })
            </script>
        <?php
        }
    ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Espero te sirva